# How to enable actuator endpoints which are set in custom starter / library?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have got custom starter application (library) which has actuator and prometheus dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in application.properties

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, prometheus`

I am using this starter in my other applications and I want to pass also this exposition of the endpoints from the starter.
Actuator and Prometheus dependecies works in applications but not show selected endpoints in starter. Ofc I can add also line with `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, prometheus` to my apps but with several apps using this starter I want to pass this once for all and change endpoints only in starter if needed.

Do you have an idea how to expose those endpoints in my app which are set in starter?

Spring Boot v2.3.2 /
Maven 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this as command line args or as ENV vars to your jar, when you start your application.

This way you can pass it to required application, as and when needed w/o updating application.properties.

It will also safeguard against exposing the actuator endpoints when not required, as actuator endpoints reveal sensitive info about the application.

eg. `java -Dmanagement.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, prometheus -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: Thank you Mahesh for your answer. Unfortunately this solution cannot be applied to our apps structure.